# com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat7

I have this problem when I deploy my war USING **mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar** on a Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) JVM: 1.7.0_79-b14  compiled with **JDK 1.7**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    com.tdk.callbacks.CallBacksListener.doGet(CallBacksListener.java:45)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

This one when I compile with **1.8**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/tdk/callbacks/CallBacksListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.tdk.callbacks.CallBacksListener)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and this one with the **1.6**:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

Comment: do you care to upvote the accepted answer as well? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not with compilation. The problem is that you try to **run** your Tomcat with deployed application using java 7. As your mysql driver and, potentially, your application are compiled with java 8, you have to use java 8 to run Tomcat

Comment: Hi. I used Java 7 to compile the code on RHEL. I have MySQL 8.0.17 and mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar and I am facing the same error. The code can only be compiled with java 7 what should be the correct combination for me to fix my error? Any help is appreciated @Nikem

Comment: @BabarBaig as it is said in the answer: "you have to use java 8 to run" your application

Comment: Basically, I was trying to Build Apache Ranger. The requirement was to use Java 7 due to some restrictions of Apache Ranger. So I was successfully able to build and install Apache Ranger using the following.

1. Java 7
2. MySQL 5.1
3. Python 2.7
4. JDBC Connector 5.1.6

Thanks @Nikem

Comment: THANK, you're a life saver !